# Custom widget is not showing up in my eclipse 4 application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to use a widget offered by [Opal](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/).
I am doing the following:

```
@PostConstruct  
public void createControls(Composite parent){  
   System.out.println("PROP3");  

   parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));        
   Composite propertyContainer = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);  
   propertyContainer.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));  

   GridData gd = new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true);  
   propertyContainer.setLayoutData(gd);  

   propertyTable = new PropertyTable(propertyContainer, SWT.NONE);  
   propertyTable.showButtons();  
   propertyTable.viewAsCategories();  

   propertyTable.addProperty(new PTProperty("id", "Identifier", "Description for identifier", "My id")).setCategory("General");  

   propertyTable.addProperty(new PTProperty("text", "Description", "Description for the description field", "blahblah...")).setCategory("General");         

}  

@Focus  
private boolean setFocus(){  
   return true;  
}
```

The code is associated with a `Part` and it runs and have no problem with other widgets but the `PropertyTable` is not displayed.
The code to create the `PropertyTable` is from their [tutorial](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/source/browse/src/test/java/org/mihalis/opal/propertyTable/PropertyTableSnippet.java).
What am I messing up here and the `PropertyTable` is not being displayed?

Comment: I am not sure that's the reason, but you aren't setting any layout data on the `propertyTable`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov:You are right!This solves it.Put it as an answer and I will mark it as accepted.BTW do you have any idea why in their tutorial snippet using a `Tab` they don't need to set the data to the `PropertyTable` and still it works?

Comment: @Cratylus I'll just add that your setFocus() should place focus in an appropriate widget if applicable, otherwise clicking on the part tab might not put keyboard focus in your view.

Comment: @PaulWebster:Thank your for the tip!Much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You (usually) need to set layout data on any controls under a composite with a `GridLayout`. `TabFolder`s use their own layout which doesn't need any layout data.